# Access data in datagridview from a class

Tags: c#, class, datagridview

I've read a lot of topics on this issue but I'm not finding an answer. I'm fairly new to this so please bear with me.

I'm trying to pass values from datagridview to a list. And then in a new class I want to make som methods accessing that list. Trouble is that when I pass the datagridview it returns it without content and values which means I can't do anything with it.

The code under ////TESTING//// works like I want. I create an instance of the specified list and it's counting the amount of rows properly, see screenshot.

```
    public List<vertEl> getVertList = new List<vertEl>();

    //Opens the file dialog and assigns file path to Textbox
    OpenFileDialog browseButton = new OpenFileDialog();
    private void browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        browseButton.Filter = "Excel Files |*.xlsx;*.xls;*.xlsm;*.csv";
        if (browseButton.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //SOME CODE TO GET DATA FROM EXCEL AND SOME METHODS TO CALCULATE
            //VALUES TO PASS TO THE TAB VERTIKALELEMENTER TAB IN MY DATAGRIDVIEW
            //VERTIKALELEMENTER IS vertElementerDgv IN MY CODE

            ////TESTING////
            GetVertElementasList TEST = new GetVertElementasList();
            getVertList =  TEST.vertList(vertElementerDgv);
            MessageBox.Show(getVertList.Count.ToString());


        }
        else return;
    }
```

I now want to do this in a seperate class and call a method from that class to do the same but when I try that with code underneath I do not get the same count as when I have the code in form1 (public partial class BridgeGeometry). It return count of 0. The method foo() is assigned to the button 1 in the form.

```
class GetKoord
{
    public GetVertElementasList getList = new GetVertElementasList();

    BridgGeometry obj = new BridgGeometry();

    public void foo()
    {
        var TEST = getList.vertList(obj.vertElementerDgv);
        //var TEST = obj.getVertList;
        MessageBox.Show(TEST.Count.ToString());

    }

}
```

I also tried to get the values directly from the datagridview but there's nothing in it when I access it from a class which is not the form1/BridgeGeometry class.

[Form - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vn0y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the link I managed to get this working. Probably not the best solution, but a working one. I tried to wrap my head around databinding, listbinding etc. but since the class with the input values are a messy one I gave that up for now. The datagriview input values are a little from lists and some from other datagridview.

[MSDN-forum: Accessing Form1 controls from a different class](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a5e3b46e-8d45-4c45-a3d6-20a25b746825/accessing-form1-controls-from-a-different-class?forum=winforms)

Explanations are given in the link so I'll just provide how I did it in my program.

If my GetKoord class are like this:

```
    public class GetKoord
    {
    private BridgGeometry bridgeGeometry;

    public GetKoord(BridgGeometry form1)
    {
        bridgeGeometry = form1;
    }

    public List<vertElementerParam> getListvertElementer(List<vertElementerParam> theList)
    {
        //var vertElementerDgv = bridgeGeometry.vertElementerDgv;
        GetVertElementasList getVertElementasList = new GetVertElementasList();
        List<vertElementerParam> MyDgvListList = new List<vertElementerParam>();
        MyDgvListList = getVertElementasList.vertList(bridgeGeometry.vertElementerDgv);

        //MessageBox.Show(MyDgvListList.Count.ToString());

        theList = MyDgvListList;
        return theList;
    }

    }
```

then I can get the list in Button1_Click like this, check the screenshot in the first post:

```
    public List<vertElementerParam> getVertList = new List<vertElementerParam>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    GetKoord getKoord = new GetKoord(this);
    List<vertElementerParam> testList = new List<vertElementerParam>();

    testList = getKoord.getListvertElementer(getVertList);
    MessageBox.Show(testList.Count.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run a loop and store the information with selected rows into a public var with something like this:

```
            string itemOne = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value + string.Empty;
            string itemTwo= dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value + string.Empty;
            string itemThree = dgMasterGridBun.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value + string.Empty;
```

Variables

```
           public var varItemOne = itemOne;
           public var varItemTwo = itemTwo;
           public var varItemThree = itemThree;
```

Comment: Please explain with this code how it helps me accessing my datagridview from an external class? The problem isn't to store the values - it's access it in another class.

Comment: Just a theory, but if you can pull your information form your data grid view and store it as a public variable, you should be able to access it(I woud assume with a getter and setter). I would of  rather just commented and brainstormed, but need 50 rep to comment lol

Comment: Or possibly store the info in an XML Check this out, might get your brain ticking. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040165/how-i-can-save-a-datagridview-in-a-xml-and-load-a-xml-to-datagridview

Comment: Think that maybe overcomplicate things