# Incomplete XML file while attempting to save data from DataGridView into XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml, windows, visual-studio

I am trying to create some XML files so that in a disconnected architecture the data can be viewed directly from the XML files.
Currently, I have some data pulled in datagridview.
However, when I attempt to save this data in an XML file, the resulting file contains "" only. Nothing else, all blank.
Please suggest how can I proceed with it.

```
 private void btnSXAAMclientinfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string varGUID;
            varGUID = txtClientGUID.Text;
            clsBusinessLogic objBL = new clsBusinessLogic();
            DataSet datasetAM = objBL.LoadSXAAMClientInfo(varGUID);
            dgvPatientData.DataSource = datasetAM.Tables[0].DefaultView;


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (int i = 1; i < dgvPatientData.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(dgvPatientData.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText);
                dt.Columns.Add(column);

            }
            int ColumnCount = dgvPatientData.Columns.Count;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvPatientData.Rows)
            {
                DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
                {
                    dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i];
                }
            }

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            XmlTextWriter newXml = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:/FK.xml");         `       System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            ds.WriteXml(newXml);


        }
```

Comment: Where's the SQL? (It's tagged sql, but I can't find any SQL in the question.)

Comment: Can we see real code, including proper formatting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can save a DatagridView in a Xml and Load A Xml to datagridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040165/how-i-can-save-a-datagridview-in-a-xml-and-load-a-xml-to-datagridview)

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot to add the newly created row to the table:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dgvPatientData.Rows)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                dataRow[i] = dr.Cells[i];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow); //<-- 
        }
```

[Read this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx) for further details.